# How to prevent Chrome extension to add multiple listeners

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have the following code in my popup.js:

```
function setDomain(domain) {      
   $.ajax({
        url: "http://example.com/api/" + domain,
        type: "GET",
        success: function (returnedData) {
          //do sth with returnedData
        }
   })
}


chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function requestEvents(request, sender, sendResponse) {

    if (request.task==="showPopup"){
         chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function (tabs) {
         chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {from: 'popup', subject: 'domainName'}, setDomain);});
    }
  }
);
```

When a user is opening multiple tabs this leads to having multiple addListener events when user decides to click the browser action.

background.js looks like this:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(){
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs){
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({task: "showPopup"});
  })
});
```

I tried multiple things but haven't been able to get it to work properly. I experimented with hasListener and removeListener like described here: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/events but could not get it to work. I'm not sure how should I use removeListener. I added at the end of function requestEvents (in popup.js) but it didn't seem to remove the listener. Also do not know how to check which listeners are currently appended.

What should I do to prevent adding multiple listeners when opening multiple tabs?

EDIT:
In content.js I have:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (msg, sender, response) {
  if ((msg.from === 'popup') && (msg.subject === 'domainName')) {
    var domainName = document.domain;
    domainName = extractDomain(domainName)
    response(domainName)
  }
}

var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.id="iframe-pl"
iframe.frameBorder = "none";
iframe.src = chrome.extension.getURL("popup.html")
```

As can be seen from above code I inject popup.html into a website.

popup.html looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <link href="stylesheets/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="stylesheets/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu|Hind|Varela|Lato:300,400,500,600,700,900", rel="stylesheet", type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="title white">
    ...
```

So the question is how does one prevent adding multiple listeners when opening multiple tabs?
Any answers would be appreciated ...

Comment: Wait, what is popup.js? Where is it loaded? Anyway, I think you can simply check sender.tab && sender.tab.id === tabs[0].id

Comment: "I experimented with hasListener and removeListener like described here: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/events but could not get it to work." What did you try? What errors did you get?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that *duplicates the problem*. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions you almost always need to include your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML, and often webpage HTML/scripts. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't my code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: I added the contents I have in content.js and in popup.html. @wOxxOm I load popup.js when user clicks browser action - or so I thought? It probably loads everytime a new tab is opened ... 1. Tab is opened. 2. Content.js script is loaded with a tab and popup.js is inserted with it. 3. Listener from popup.js is added to listen for messages from background.js 'show popup'. --> It looks like the 3rd step listeners are being added everytime a user clicks browser action (I think). So my question is how to prevent multiple listeners to being added in popup.js?

Comment: @pvg I added: 

    chrome.extension.onRequest.removeListener(requestEvents);

in varius places inside popup.js function requestEvents. It didn't throw any errors but it also did not seem to remove the listener. Since multiple times the setDomain method was called ... I probably don't know how to correctly use removeListener method?

Comment: @wOxxOm as you suggested I added 
    `chrome.runtime.sendMessage({task: "showPopup", sender_id: tabs[0].id});` in background.js and wrapped 
              `if (request.sender_id === tabs[0].id){  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {from: 'popup', subject: 'domainName'}, setDomain);}`
But still this piece of code is being called multiple times. I checked the sender_id and was for the same tab. Possibly I should add a listener only for a specific tab or ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this **background.js**:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(){
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs){
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({task: "showPopup"});
  })
});
```

This will query for the active tab, but send a message to ALL listeners. According to [docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-sendMessage):

> If sending to your extension, the runtime.onMessage event will be
>   fired in every frame of your extension (except for the sender's frame)

Try replacing `chrome.runtime.sendMessage({task: "showPopup"});` with `chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id,{task: "showPopup"})` to send the message to only the active tab.

Apart from that, you are including 2 message listeners per webpage: one in `content.js` (that I assume is a content script) and another one in `popup.js` that gets loaded when you insert `popup.html` in an iframe in the webpage.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I believe it solved my issue (I actually tried changing this before and from memory it didn't work -> but I tried again now and it looks like it does - probably did not test well the first time). I will let it run for a day when I'm visiting websites, if all is good - and it looks like it is - I will accept your answer and give you 200 credit. Thank you again Ivan. p.s. Is there something wrong with having 2 message listeners at the same time or what did you want to hint  ...? :)

Comment: @necker No, nothing wrong with having as many listeners as you want. I just found it a little strange, but if it fits the architecture of your extension, it's all good. Happy to help :)

Comment: @necker I'm glad it all worked correctly. Happy coding!